# Is it not possible to sequentially animate CSS scaleX and CSS scaleY?

Tags: css

```
animation: scale-down-X 1.4s, scale-down-Y 1.4s;
```

As one can surmise 'scale-down-x' and 'scale-down-y' simply refer to @keyframes that perform: scaleX(0) and scaleY(0).

In this simple case, of course I can just do scale() and control both 'X' and 'Y' together. However, the eventual goal is to have 'X' and 'Y' work indpendently.

Currently, Chrome just ignores what is before the comma and ONLY does the 'second' animation.

My assumption here is just that 'chaining' scaleX and scaleY is just not feasible...

Comment: share code sample ?

Comment: You are not actually animating scaleX and scaleY - those aren't CSS _properties_, they are just functions. What you are actually animating is the `transform` property. And if you have one animation that tries to set `transform: scaleX(...)` and another one that at the same time tries to set `transform: scaleY(...)` - well then your second animation will _overwrite_ the value your first one just tried to set. That is not Chrome's fault, but one in your understanding of how setting CSS properties works. There is no automatic "concatenation" of the two values happening here or anything like that.

Comment: Yeah. It makes sense. Just like transition x and y is same situation. Thanks for pointing out my faulty understanding.